# How to show the whole problem (LP/MILP, SCIP)

Tags: or-tools

How to show the whole LP/MILP problem.

I am using `solver(MPSolver::CreateSolver("SCIP"))` in `c++`.

I saw this [issue](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/520) and [this reply](https://github.com/google/or-tools/issues/520#issuecomment-577770011). However, those are not helpful for `SCIP`.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches:

**Option A:** get the underlying solver, use the scip solver to export the model.

in, details: use the [underlying_solver](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.h#L742) method on the LinearSolver class.

Then cast the returned pointer to SCIP* (see [the implementation of this method for the SCIP solver](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/ortools/linear_solver/scip_interface.cc#L124)).

Now you have the solver, you can use the solver's API for anything including exporting the model. The only limitation is that you need the solver to have loaded the model, which only happens at solve time.

**Option B:**

call one the two [export methods](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/2cb85b4eead4c38e1c54b48044f92087cf165bce/ortools/linear_solver/linear_solver.h#L624). This API is also available in non C++ languages.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Option B worked for my case.